# How to rewrite an URL in .htaccess to access a Slim-rendered page?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, slim

I'm trying to make a RewriteRule in .htaccess so that when users visit http://domain.com/pages/1 they actually get a page rendered by Slim framework accessible at http://domain.com/api/v1/pages/1.

The folder structure is as follows:

```
/api
    -index.php  <-- This is a Slim index file
    -.htaccess  <-- This is a Slim .htaccess (unmodified)
/components
    -page.php   <-- This is a page template that I use for rendering in Slim    
index.php       <-- This is a homepage
.htaccess       <-- This is my wwwroot .htaccess
```

My page.php template looks like this:

```
<?php 
?>
echo 'This is a page'
```

Here's the Slim part (for the sake of simplicity it doesn't yet pass the $id' variable to the template):

```
$app->group('/v1', function () use ($app) {
    $app->get('/pages/:id', function ($id) use ($app) {
        $app->render('../../components/page.php');
    });
});
```

The rewrite rule in .htaccess under wwwroot is:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^pages/([0-9]*)?$ api/v1/pages/$1 [L]
```

There are two weird things that bother me:

1. In this configuration accessing the page at http://domain.com/api/v1/pages/1 works, but it doesn't work at http://domain.com/pages/1
2. When I try to access http://domain.com/pages/1 I get a 404 error, which is generated by Slim, rather than apache.

My question is as follows:

What is the correct/proper .htaccess rewrite rule to rewrite an URL for a page rendered by Slim in the above mentioned scenario?

Answer (score 0):

This is due to improper rewrite pattern.

Try

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^pages/([0-9]*)?$ api/v1/pages/$1
```

Comment: My bad. The rule was supposed to include ([0-9]*) but I omitted it for some reason. RewriteRule ^pages/([0-9]*)?$ api/v1/pages/$1 doesn't work